# Как добавить LineShape между элементами - источниками событий?

Tags: c#, события, winforms

Есть класс Unit : Label, экземпляры которого выводятся на Panel. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы можно было **добавить LineShape между элементами, которые выступают в качестве sender-ов в событиях MouseLeftButtonDown и MouseLeftButtonUp**. Загвоздка в том, что в EventHandler для объекта можно передавать только static методы, а **добавить LineShape на форму из статического метода нельзя**. В чем моя ошибка?

З. Ы. не судите строго, в WinForms полез позавчера, и пока в них не ориентируюсь вообще.

UPD 1

```
static void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Unit from = start; // sender as Unit в MouseDown
    Unit to = sender as Unit; // проверки на null пока уберу
    Panel control = to.Parent as Panel; // как-то получить родителя
    start = null;
    LineShape line = new LineShape(from.Location.X, from.Location.Y, 
        to.Location.X, to.Location.Y);
    control.Controls.Add(line);
}
```

тут в последней строчке ошибка Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.LineShape" в "System.Windows.Forms.Control" невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

> в EventHandler для объекта можно передавать только static методы

Вот это сомнительно. Вообще говоря, обработчиком может быть нестатический метод объекта.

> преобразование типа из "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.LineShape" в "System.Windows.Forms.Control" невозможно

Собственно, говорит само за себя. `LineShape` не является WinForms-контролом.

Comment: Чем можно заменить LineShape? Или как по-другому обойти ситуацию?

Comment: В WinForms такого контрола нет, рисовать придется средствами класса [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx). Как вариант - написать или найти готовый контрол для линии.

Comment: Готовый контрол для линии. РЖАЧ.....  Может панель добавь с закраской?????? Ну в общем надо 1. CustomControl, 2. Paint(){e.Graphics.DrawLine();.... } 3. Желательно настроить аттрибуты SetStyle(). 4. Для обрезки ненужных частей смотри в сторону UserControl.Region. Удачи